# Mount partition at /var/log during install

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, system-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu 16.04 with manual partitioning, and need to choose a separate partition for /var/log. However, in the installer, there does not seem to be an option for doing this. The drop-down menu only has /, /boot, /home, /tmp, /usr, /var, /srv, /opt, and /usr/local.

What is the easiest way to put /var/log on a separate partition?

Comment: You can type in a mountpoint during the installation

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/343370/15811 Has all you need to know, example uses a /windows as a mount point.

Comment: Why is it necessary for you to do manual partitioning? Are you a first time Ubuntu user? I ask because most manual partitioning ends up with 1) too many unnecessary partitions, and 2) wrongly sized partitions. Why not use the standard partitioning?